# Change text font size in Bokeh LabelSet

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I have some plots deployed as a layout using Bokeh Server. For now it is working fine. But when I include the `text_font_size` attribute in the label set, it does not work anymore.

```
labels = LabelSet(x='datetime', y='bool_event', text='Code description', level='glyph',
                  x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=ColumnDataSource(df2), render_mode='canvas',
                  text_font_size=10)
```

The error I get is the following:
[image: Error]

The actual layout is the following one:
[image: Layout]

Comment: Anyone aware of a way to set the label font sizes in the source data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give units to your text_font_size. The code should look like this:

```
  labels = LabelSet(x='datetime', y='bool_event', text='Code description', level='glyph',
              x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=ColumnDataSource(df2), render_mode='canvas',
              text_font_size="10pt")
```